# Export two constants from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

So im trying to export the two constants latitude and longitude to another component, its not a child or parent of the component with the constants in so I cannot use context or props. I tried exporting as a named variable but because the constants are defined within the Header component they are out of scope for the export statements. Someone please fix this for me, Im going to cry if i spend anymore time trying to fix it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 

function Header() {

    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(0);
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(0);


    function handleChange(event) {
        setText(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleClick() {
        const geoCoderURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + text + "&limit=5&appid={apikey}"
        function getCoordinates(url) {
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                setLatitude(response.data[0].lat);
                setLongitude(response.data[0].lon);
            });
        } 
        getCoordinates(geoCoderURL);        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Five Day Forecast</h1> 
            <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="name" autoFocus placeholder="Enter location here."/>
            <button type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>Forecast</button> 
        </div>
    )
}

export const locationLat = latitude;
export const locationLon = longitude;
export default Header;
```

Comment: I need the value of the two constants to update if a new input is inputted by the user, so thats why I am using two states

Comment: So the component you want to pass the values to is a sibling of the Header component? What would be the parent of these two components? You could pass the values UP to this parent, then DOWN again to the component that needs them... that's the React way of doing it anyway...

Comment: *so I cannot use context or props*. No, the Context API would be perfect for this. Please clarify why this isn't an option.

Comment: because  i want to pass the constants to a sibling component of the Header component, and doesnt the Context API only works between parent and child no?

Comment: so using context I would then send the constants up to the App() component then pass then into the other child component, any idea how to do that?

Comment: The Context API provides a way to allow every child component inside the context to access data from the context. This way any parent, child, sibling or otherwise can share info, as long as they're in the same context. I'll work something out for you.

Comment: Ok thank you, im new to React so not really exprienced with context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic setup of a Context. This particular example shows the creation of a context, a wrapper that holds the state inside the context, and a custom hook to access the context values from any component.

The provider component looks just like a regular component except for the `Context.Provider` part. This is the part of the context that exposes the values of the context to its descendants.

```
// coordinates-context.js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

/**
 * Create a new context.
 */
const CoordinatesContext = createContext();

/**
 * Create a provider wrapper which is responsible for the state 
 * and children of the context. In a lot of ways it works just like
 * a normal component, except for the Provider part, which is special
 * for the Context API.
 */
export const CoordinatesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({ lat: null, lng: null });

  return (
    <CoordinatesContext.Provider value={[coordinates, setCoordinates]}>
      {children}
    </CoordinatesContext.Provider>
  );
};

/**
 * This custom hook will allow us you use the context in any component.
 */
export const useCoordinatesContext = useContext(CoordinatesContext);
```

The provider component should have the components that need the data as descendants, like the example below.

```
<App>
  <CoordinatesProvider>
    <Header/>
    <OtherComponent/>
  </CoordinatesProvider>
</App>
```

Now that all the descendants have access, we can use the custom hook to use and manipulate the exposed values.

Our context simply exposes a state, so the implementation works just like how you would use a `useState` hook.

The only difference now is that all components that use the context, will be updated whenever any component updates the state inside of the context.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useCoordinatesContext } from '../your-path-to/coordinates-context.js';
import axios from 'axios'; 

function Header() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  /**
   * The hook exposes the useState values from the context provider.
   */
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useCoordinatesContext();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setText(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    const geoCoderURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + text + "&limit=5&appid={apikey}";

    function getCoordinates(url) {
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {

        /**
         * Update context state.
         */
        setCoordinates({
          lat: response.data[0].lat,
          lng: response.data[0].lon
        });
      });
    } 
    getCoordinates(geoCoderURL);        
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Five Day Forecast</h1> 
      <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="name" autoFocus placeholder="Enter location here."/>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>Forecast</button> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't export the state outside the functional component as a constant, but there are lots of solutions you can adopt to solve your problem.

1. Using React.createContext and React.useContext hook. If you define the hook in the parent of all components that needs it, you won't have problems with the access (most of the time this parent is the App component).
2. Using a state manager, like Redux. This lets you access getters and setters anywhere in the application.
   Note: Redux adds a bit of boilerplate in the application, so if you don't already use it, prefer the first solution.
3. Saving the coordinates in the localStorage.
   IMO this is almost never a good solution because doesn't allow you to be notified when the coordinates are updated, but fits well in some scenarios.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).